# JavaFX LoadException while loading fxml-file

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

Im trying to use fxml and JavaFX for my application.
But when the fxmlLoader load my file, i receive the following error:

javafx.fxml.LoadException: Font is not a valid type.

I really do not understand why. In a other Interface I use exactly the same label.
the fxml code of the used label:

```
<Label fx:id="blueLabel" alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="Infinity"
       prefHeight="10.0" textFill="#054682" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <font>
        <Font size="1.0" />
    </font>
</Label>
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the `Font` as

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
```

or with wildcard

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
```

in the FXML file.